# Docker container with .net and react app not loading client

Tags: reactjs, .net, docker

To Begin I have created .net core 6  project with react.js from visual studio 2022.
I have added docker to my project as well.

I have been following this tutorial.
"Quickstart: Use Docker with a React Single-page App in Visual Studio"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-tools-react?view=vs-2022

I came to the point where I'm able to build my image however when I'm starting my docker container it is running only my backend api, react app/client is not loading at all.

Any Ideas?

here is how my docker file looks like

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["admin_tool_api_ui/admin_tool_api_ui.csproj", "admin_tool_api_ui/"]
RUN dotnet restore "admin_tool_api_ui/admin_tool_api_ui.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/admin_tool_api_ui"
RUN dotnet build "admin_tool_api_ui.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "admin_tool_api_ui.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "admin_tool_api_ui.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I feel your pain. Thanks to Microsoft documentation I'm now a person with high level of patiency, I learned to accept things as they are in life.

Second, I think you are missing the front-end build, which is this piece:

```
FROM node:16 AS build-web
COPY ./admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package.json /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package.json
COPY ./admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package-lock.json /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package-lock.json
WORKDIR /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp
RUN npm ci
COPY ./admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/ /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp
RUN npm run build
```

So your final `Dockerfile` can be something like this:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["admin_tool_api_ui/admin_tool_api_ui.csproj", "admin_tool_api_ui/"]
RUN dotnet restore "admin_tool_api_ui/admin_tool_api_ui.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/admin_tool_api_ui"
RUN dotnet build "admin_tool_api_ui.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "admin_tool_api_ui.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM node:16 AS build-web
COPY ./admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package.json /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package.json
COPY ./admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package-lock.json /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/package-lock.json
WORKDIR /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp
RUN npm ci
COPY ./admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/ /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp
RUN npm run build




FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=build-web /admin_tool_api_ui/ClientApp/build ./ClientApp/build
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "admin_tool_api_ui.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set property "Copy to Output directory" = "Copy always" for all React related files  ClientApp directory hierarchy via "Properties" dialog.